# Been getting Underfull \hbox a lot. Could someone share a good practice manual?

Tags: spacing

I'm new to TeX, currently switching from Overleaf to WinEdt (trial edition), but I'm following blindly the TeX philosophy of "just write, the editor does all the work for you".

As a result, I'm getting this "warning"? a lot.

I tend to make big condensed paragraphs. In my documents, the new paragraphs start with one line identation. I have read that underfull `\hbox` only appears when you're trying to put some chunk of text like an url that doesn't fit in a line. (That was the help from Overleaf.)

What should I do to avoid this? Is this a signal that my text has poor readability?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but you really do not provide much information on what specifically causes these underfull box warnings. What kind of answer do you expect to get? Something similarly specific like "Try the usual methods."? If you provide more context, your chances of getting a specific answer will probably increase.

Comment: Does "one line indentation" mean that you have `\\ ` anywhere? If yes, remove them.

Comment: _overfull_ means that you have too much text to fit in the line, Underfull means that there is _not enough_ text (or white space) to fill the specified space. But if you do not show the warning you get, nor the code that produces the warning then there is no real answer that can be given. Please fix your question so that it has enough information.

Comment: I don't understand. Obviously I wrote too much text to fit in the line, but the final pdf wraps it and even hyphens words so it is centered and clean. Why the warning then?